# Unable to locate JDK in Linux VM

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to locate the JDK to setup jstatd but I am unable to locate it.

When I type `java -version` I get the following response

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Then I tried locating it using the following 2 commands:

1. `which java`

Response: `/usr/bin/java`

I tried to `cd` it but I get `-bash: cd: /usr/bin/java: Not a directory`

2. Then I tried this `whereis java`
   Response: 
   `java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`

I again tried to cd it. But still not a directory.
Where could it be installed?

Comment: After the answers, you said you found it in /usr/lib/jvm. That's where the JVM is located; you are asking about the JDK. You should do `which javac`.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou Yes I too thought the same. So I never checked the `jvm` dir. But I found the JDK inside the `jvm` dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually jdk's and jre's are located under `/usr/lib/java` or `/usr/lib/jvm`. To be sure, do an `ls -la $(which java)`, it should be a symlink pointing to the real binary (You could have to repeat this operation, usually if there are alternatives this link could point to another link).

Comment: Thanks! Found it in /usr/lib/jvm . I was not aware that it could be there too.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `java` binary is not a symbolic link (maybe of a second level)? I'm pretty sure it is.

Just run `ls -l` on `/usr/bin/java` and discover the actual location.

For me, the final actual location is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`:

```
dmitry@dginzburg-win:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
dmitry@dginzburg-win:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
dmitry@dginzburg-win:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  14 16:23 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
dmitry@dginzburg-win:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Aug  14 16:23 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
dmitry@dginzburg-win:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
bin  docs  jre  man
```

Comment: Yup. I found it in /usr/lib/jvm/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/java is not directory file. You can find the final location java file as below;

```
readlink -f $(which java);
```

default location jdk is usualy in /usr/lib/jvm/

Eg; my config is :

```
user@host:$ ls -alrt /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec 19  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

/usr/bin/java links to /etc/alternatives/java

```
user@host:$ ls -alrt /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul  7  2015 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

/etc/alternatives/java links to  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

```
user@host:$/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin$ ls -arlt /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7734 Mar 27  2016 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

first letter - in -rwxr-xr-x means that this file type is file not directory.

Comment: `/etc/alternatives/java` is another symlink, this one should point to the real one.